# In R, how to transform row values into new columns

Tags: r, model.matrix

I have a dataframe "mydf" created with the following:

```
x <- rep(1,100)
y <- rnorm(100,1)
z <- rep("A",25)
z <- append(append(append(z, rep("B",25)), rep("C",25)), rep("D",25))
mydf <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
```

As you'll notice, z has four distinct values (A, B, C and D).
Now what I want to do is create four new fields named z_A, z_B, z_C and z_D where each is populated with a 0 or 1. If mydf$z==A, then z_A should be 1. If mydf$z==B, then z_B should be 1 otherwise 0, and so on for each of the values.

While I only have four distinct values in mydf$z now, I'm trying to get to a general purpose function I can use to binarize any column which can have any number of distinct values.

I've looked at another example on StackOverflow such as:

```
a <- model.matrix( ~ z - 1, data=mydf)
```

which works great when the column has only character values.

```
> a
    zA zB zC zD
1    1  0  0  0
2    1  0  0  0
3    1  0  0  0
4    1  0  0  0
5    1  0  0  0
6    1  0  0  0
7    1  0  0  0
8    1  0  0  0
9    1  0  0  0
10   1  0  0  0
```

When I try it with column z as a numeric variable:

```
x <- rep(1,100)
y <- rnorm(100,1)
z <- rep(1,25)
z <- append(append(append(z, rep(2,25)), rep(3,25)), rep(4,25))
mydf <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
c <- model.matrix( ~ z - 1, data=mydf)
c
```

I get:

```
> c
    z
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
10  1
```

If I try setting the desired variable as character, I get the following which is fine except the field names are all screwy:

```
c <- model.matrix( ~ as.character(z) - 1, data=mydf)
> c
    as.character(z)1 as.character(z)2 as.character(z)3 as.character(z)4
1                  1                0                0                0
2                  1                0                0                0
3                  1                0                0                0
4                  1                0                0                0
5                  1                0                0                0
6                  1                0                0                0
7                  1                0                0                0
8                  1                0                0                0
9                  1                0                0                0
10                 1                0                0                0
```

Please let me know if there's additional info that would be helpful to solve this.

Thank you!

EDIT:
Here's an example of some actual data per Howard's feedback.

```
dput(head(df,100))

structure(list(datetime = structure(c(14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 
14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 
14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 
14975, 14975, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 
14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 
14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14977, 14977, 
14977, 14977, 14977, 14977, 14977, 14977, 14977, 14977, 14977, 
14977, 14977, 14977, 14977, 14977, 14977, 14977, 14977, 14977, 
14977, 14977, 14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 
14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 
14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 14978, 14979, 14979, 
14979, 14979, 14979, 14979, 14979, 14979), class = "Date"), season = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), holiday = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), workingday = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), weather = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), temp = c(9.84, 9.02, 
9.02, 9.84, 9.84, 9.84, 9.02, 8.2, 9.84, 13.12, 15.58, 14.76, 
17.22, 18.86, 18.86, 18.04, 17.22, 18.04, 17.22, 17.22, 16.4, 
16.4, 16.4, 18.86, 18.86, 18.04, 17.22, 18.86, 18.86, 17.22, 
16.4, 16.4, 15.58, 14.76, 14.76, 14.76, 14.76, 14.76, 13.94, 
13.94, 13.94, 14.76, 13.12, 12.3, 10.66, 9.84, 9.02, 9.02, 8.2, 
6.56, 6.56, 5.74, 5.74, 5.74, 6.56, 7.38, 8.2, 9.02, 9.84, 10.66, 
10.66, 10.66, 9.84, 9.84, 8.2, 8.2, 7.38, 5.74, 7.38, 6.56, 6.56, 
5.74, 5.74, 4.92, 4.92, 4.92, 5.74, 6.56, 6.56, 9.02, 9.02, 9.84, 
10.66, 11.48, 12.3, 11.48, 10.66, 9.84, 9.84, 9.02, 9.02, 8.2, 
8.2, 6.56, 6.56, 9.84, 9.02, 8.2, 7.38, 8.2), atemp = c(14.395, 
13.635, 13.635, 14.395, 14.395, 12.88, 13.635, 12.88, 14.395, 
17.425, 19.695, 16.665, 21.21, 22.725, 22.725, 21.97, 21.21, 
21.97, 21.21, 21.21, 20.455, 20.455, 20.455, 22.725, 22.725, 
21.97, 21.21, 22.725, 22.725, 21.21, 20.455, 20.455, 19.695, 
17.425, 16.665, 16.665, 17.425, 17.425, 16.665, 16.665, 16.665, 
16.665, 14.395, 13.635, 11.365, 10.605, 11.365, 9.85, 8.335, 
6.82, 6.82, 5.305, 6.82, 6.06, 6.82, 8.335, 9.09, 10.605, 10.605, 
12.12, 12.12, 12.12, 11.365, 12.88, 12.88, 11.365, 9.85, 7.575, 
10.605, 9.09, 9.09, 7.575, 9.09, 7.575, 7.575, 7.575, 7.575, 
7.575, 6.82, 10.605, 11.365, 11.365, 12.88, 13.635, 14.395, 13.635, 
12.88, 12.88, 12.88, 13.635, 12.88, 11.365, 12.88, 9.85, 9.85, 
11.365, 11.365, 9.85, 9.09, 9.09), humidity = c(81L, 80L, 80L, 
75L, 75L, 75L, 80L, 86L, 75L, 76L, 76L, 81L, 77L, 72L, 72L, 77L, 
82L, 82L, 88L, 88L, 87L, 87L, 94L, 88L, 88L, 94L, 100L, 94L, 
94L, 77L, 76L, 71L, 76L, 81L, 71L, 66L, 66L, 76L, 81L, 71L, 57L, 
46L, 42L, 39L, 44L, 44L, 47L, 44L, 44L, 47L, 47L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
43L, 43L, 40L, 35L, 35L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 32L, 47L, 47L, 64L, 
69L, 55L, 55L, 59L, 63L, 63L, 68L, 74L, 74L, 69L, 64L, 69L, 51L, 
51L, 56L, 52L, 52L, 49L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 64L, 64L, 69L, 64L, 
74L, 74L, 48L, 47L, 47L, 43L, 40L), windspeed = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 6.0032, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16.9979, 19.0012, 19.0012, 19.9995, 19.0012, 
19.9995, 19.9995, 19.0012, 16.9979, 16.9979, 16.9979, 12.998, 
15.0013, 19.9995, 19.9995, 16.9979, 19.0012, 12.998, 12.998, 
19.9995, 12.998, 15.0013, 15.0013, 15.0013, 16.9979, 19.9995, 
8.9981, 12.998, 11.0014, 11.0014, 12.998, 22.0028, 30.0026, 23.9994, 
22.0028, 19.9995, 11.0014, 23.9994, 27.9993, 26.0027, 19.0012, 
26.0027, 12.998, 19.0012, 26.0027, 16.9979, 22.0028, 19.9995, 
19.0012, 19.0012, 16.9979, 16.9979, 15.0013, 7.0015, 0, 7.0015, 
8.9981, 8.9981, 7.0015, 7.0015, 7.0015, 8.9981, 6.0032, 7.0015, 
7.0015, 8.9981, 11.0014, 15.0013, 22.0028, 19.9995, 11.0014, 
12.998, 15.0013, 16.9979, 16.9979, 15.0013, 12.998, 7.0015, 7.0015, 
0, 6.0032, 6.0032, 0, 6.0032, 6.0032, 15.0013, 11.0014, 15.0013, 
12.998, 19.9995), casual = c(3L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 8L, 12L, 26L, 29L, 47L, 35L, 40L, 41L, 15L, 9L, 6L, 11L, 
3L, 11L, 15L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 16L, 20L, 
11L, 4L, 19L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 13L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 
3L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 12L, 
18L, 9L, 17L, 15L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 3L), registered = c(13L, 32L, 27L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 7L, 6L, 24L, 30L, 55L, 47L, 71L, 70L, 52L, 52L, 26L, 31L, 
25L, 31L, 17L, 24L, 13L, 16L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 19L, 46L, 
54L, 73L, 64L, 55L, 55L, 67L, 58L, 43L, 29L, 17L, 20L, 9L, 8L, 
5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 30L, 63L, 153L, 81L, 33L, 41L, 48L, 53L, 66L, 
58L, 67L, 146L, 148L, 102L, 49L, 49L, 20L, 11L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 36L, 92L, 177L, 98L, 37L, 50L, 66L, 79L, 54L, 48L, 68L, 202L, 
179L, 110L, 53L, 48L, 34L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 33L, 87L, 
192L), count = c(16L, 40L, 32L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 
36L, 56L, 84L, 94L, 106L, 110L, 93L, 67L, 35L, 37L, 36L, 34L, 
28L, 39L, 17L, 17L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 20L, 53L, 70L, 93L, 
75L, 59L, 74L, 76L, 65L, 53L, 30L, 22L, 31L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 30L, 64L, 154L, 88L, 44L, 51L, 61L, 61L, 77L, 72L, 76L, 
157L, 157L, 110L, 52L, 52L, 20L, 12L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 36L, 
94L, 179L, 100L, 42L, 57L, 78L, 97L, 63L, 65L, 83L, 212L, 182L, 
112L, 54L, 48L, 35L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 33L, 88L, 195L)), .Names = c("datetime", 
"season", "holiday", "workingday", "weather", "temp", "atemp", 
"humidity", "windspeed", "casual", "registered", "count"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100"), class = "data.frame")
```

In this case I want to create df$season1, df$season2, df$season3 and df$season4.
My question in this case is do I have to type out every column in the dataset (see dcast below) just to add the season1, season2, season3 and season4 field? AND, is there a way to name them season1, season2, season3, season4 rather than 1,2,3,4?

```
 library(reshape2)
    result <- dcast(df,datetime + holiday + workingday + weather + 
                      temp + atemp + humidity + windspeed + casual + 
    registered + count ~ season,length)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply change the z-column to character? Seems not really a hassle and you could still use the model.matrix code.

Comment: Just tried that. If I try setting the desired variable as character, I get the following which is fine except the column names show up as: as.character(z)1 as.character(z)2 as.character(z)3 as.character(z)4 and then I'd have to go back and change them somehow but I have to figure out some clever way to figure out how many columns were just added to automate it in the function.

Comment: like this `mydf$z <- as.character(mydf$z)`, I assume the 1, 2, 3, 4 are under column z.

Comment: Thanks KFB. I can get this to run when I don't  have it inside a function. However, when I create this function:
`binarize <- function(data, myvar) {
  data$myvar <- as.character(data$myvar)
  temp <- model.matrix( ~ myvar - 1, data=data)
  cbind(data,temp)
}`
then run:
 `binarize(df,season)`
it doesn't seem to be substituting data$myvar accordingly as df$season. Is there another way to specify to substitute these? This is an ongoing problem I've had substituting variables as column names.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
  cbind(mydf,sapply(levels(mydf$z), function(x) as.numeric(mydf$z==x)))     
  #    x                   y z A B C D
  #1   1    1.68876859502969 A 1 0 0 0
  #2   1   0.408336901490438 A 1 0 0 0
  #3   1  -0.115258225333019 A 1 0 0 0
  #4   1    1.64286711975319 A 1 0 0 0
  #5   1   0.393874649038152 A 1 0 0 0
  #6   1    1.55492320680662 A 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
library(reshape2)
result <- dcast(mydf,x+y~z,length)
head(result)
#   x                     y A B C D
# 1 1 -0.000774423151445491 0 0 1 0
# 2 1   -0.0206607799566461 1 0 0 0
# 3 1   -0.0374524778732928 1 0 0 0
# 4 1    -0.155943108886233 0 0 1 0
# 5 1    -0.174550152789981 0 0 0 1
# 6 1    -0.183201143770777 0 0 1 0
```

This does sort by x and y, which may not be desirable.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for with one caveat. Is there a way to name the columns zA, zB, etc? or z_A, z_B? There will likely be multiple fields I'm running this function against in which case the column names may be duplicated. Also, if I have 100 columns in my dataset, do I need to list out all the names (instead of x+y~z basically doing field1 + field2 + field3, etc?

Comment: Can you provide a more representative example of this?